# NUnit Assert.Throws swallows console output

Tags: c#, nunit, assertions

Here is a sample program to reproduce the issue:

```
[TestFixture] // NUnit ver. 3.9
public class IssueTest
{
    [Test]
    public void AssertThrowsConsoleIssue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1);
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(2);
            throw new Exception("test");
        });
        Console.WriteLine(3);
    }
}
```

I expect an output to be

```
1
2
3
```

But in reality it is

```
1
3
```

I encountered this issue when was debugging a unit test and noticed that some console log output was missing.

As for me this looks like a bug. Is there a way to prevent Assert.Throws from swallowing Console output?

Comment: If you suspect it is a bug check if the issue on exits on the Github repo,

Comment: I haven't found relevant issue on NUnit issue tracker. I've discovered a kind of a workaround - use ThrowsAssync instead of Throws. In my case instead of Assert.Throws<DbUpdateException>(() => uow.Complete()); I have to write Assert.ThrowsAsync<DbUpdateException>(() => Task.FromResult(uow.Complete())); Need more time to understand why ThrowsAssync fixes the issue, but still it looks like a hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug and you just found it! Usually bugs need to be confirmed but seeing your example I can understand exactly what is happening.

`Throws` creates a temporary test result and context, which we throw away. If we didn't do that, the thrown exception would be recorded in the result. Obviously, we need to save some things, including the text output, from that temporary result. It will be cool if you can file a bug for this on GitHub.

As a workaround, you can use an async delegate as suggested by Roman. If you do that, `Assert.Throws` will then use different code that doesn't create a throwaway context and result.

If you file a bug on this, I'll try to give you a better workaround on the issue. ;-)

Comment: Hi, Charlie. Thank you. I've created a ticket as you suggested: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2688

Comment: There's a PR to fix it but questions have been raised as to the need for it. It's my bad to have treated it only as a technical problem to solve. You should explain with some real-world use case.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, Roman's hack fixed my problem.
Waiting for the next release with the fix :)